# Will there be a standard typelist?

Tags: c++, templates, generics

Why isn't there a standard typelist in the C++ standard? I would think that something so useful for generic programming (as shown in reflection's `ObjectSequence`) would be a good candidate for standardization, instead of the myriad implementations around. Are there plans to add one?

Comment: `std::tuple` is basically a list of types

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number With a bunch of extra junk. :( Something tells me a simple `template <typename...> struct type_list {};` is less costly to instantiate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[N3416: Packaging Parameter Packs](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3416.html) proposed a language typelist, but is dead in the water since a decade back.

> A parameter pack literal is a template-parameter-list (§14p1)
> surrounded by angle brackets, like
>
> ```
> <int, std::basic_ostream<char>, 7>
> ```
>
> To name a parameter list, we just typedef it, like
>
> ```
> typedef<signed char, short int, int, long int, long long int> signed_integral_types;
> cout << contains<signed_integral_types, int>::value; // Prints true
> ```

---

[P1858: Generalized pack declaration and usage](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1858r2.html) is more likely to provide the functionality of a standard type list, as a language feature in particular contexts. The paper is still [under EWG discussion](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/612).

---

[P0949: Adding support for type-based metaprogramming to the standard library](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0949r0.html) proposed introducing

> ```
> template<class... T> struct mp_list {};
> ```

But the main scope of the paper is bringing many common Boost meta-programming library types into the standard, where a type list is an essential helper, but where e.g. `std::tuple` could likewise be used as opposed to a dedicated type.

> The fundamental data structure on which the proposed algorithms operate is the list, an instantiation of a class template whose parameters are all types. **The library does not require or prefer a specific list type.** While a canonical `mp_list` is supplied, its use is not mandatory; all operations and algorithms support other lists such as std::tuple, `std::variant` or even `std::pair` (when there is no need to add or remove elements).

However, the author mentioned in Cpplang Slack that this paper was rejected.

Answer (score 0):

> Will there be a standard typelist?

If someone proposes it, and it is voted in by the committee, then there will be.

> Why isn't there a standard typelist in the C++ standard?

Either because it hasn't been proposed, or because such proposal hasn't been voted in by the committee (yet).

You can find the proposals here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/